# simple horizontal equal div's

Tags: html, css

Ok, I'm setting up a mini-page and I want it to be 100% scalable so I'm trying to use only %.

But I don't get the "items" to take the 33% width and distribute is over the 80% of "content".

What am I doing wrong?

```css
body, html{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.menu{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    float: left;
}

.content{
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #eee;
    float: left;
}

.bottom{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.item{
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
}

.red{background: red;}
.blue{background: blue;}
.green{background: green;}
```

```html
<div class="menu">menu</div>
<div class="content">content
    <div class="bottom">
        <div class="item red">left</div>
        <div class="item blue">mid</div>
        <div class="item green">right</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/39g778n5/1/)**

```
.content{       
    position: relative; 
}

.bottom{       
    width:100%;
}

.item{       
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: I think it's worth noting that setting `position: relative` on `.content` solves a separate issue that the submitter  probably didn't (yet) know about.